# PHP cURL get content with accented URL

Tags: php, url, curl, diacritics, idn

Using cURL with an accented URL, I cannot get content if CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER = true.

Example:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Été");
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec ($curl);
echo $html;
```

$html is empty, does someone have a solution ?

Comment: Hm, this question confused me, and I copy-pasted your code and executed script - page content returned. Probably there's something wrong with your network configuration or php configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Try using [urlencode](http://www.php.net/urlencode) for the accent part of the url:

```
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/" . urlencode("Été"));
```

And see what happens.